# django models.py - migrating from one model class to another

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I am trying to break up an existing model class.  The original class is not optimal so I want to move all customer relevant information from CustomerOrder into a new class Customer.  What is the best way to do this in Django?

Old model class:

```
class CustomerOrder(models.Model):

    # Customer information fields
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)       # Customer first name
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)        # Customer last name
    email = models.EmailField()                 # Customer email address
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)      # Address to deliver (e.g. 1532 Commonwealth St. Apt 302)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)         # City to deliver   (e.g. Fullerton, CA 92014)

    # Order information fields
    note = models.TextField()           # Any notes the customer may have about shipping
    shipping_method = models.CharField(max_length=200)      # Shipping in LA or OC
    total_price = models.FloatField(default=0)              # Total price of the order
    delivery_date = models.DateField()  # When to deliver the order. Order is "live" until the next 
                            # day after delivery. So if delivery date is Jan 3, it's "live" until Jan 4.

    order_date = models.DateField()     # When the customer ordered
    time_slot = models.CharField(max_length=200)            # What time to deliver the product
    is_cancelled = models.BooleanField(default=False)       # If the order is cancelled or refunded, we mark it here.

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    # When the order entry was saved into database
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)        # When the order was last updated in database

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

New model class:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)       # Customer first name
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)        # Customer last name
    email = models.EmailField()                 # Customer email address
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)      # Address to deliver (e.g. 1532 Commonwealth St. Apt 302)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)         # City to deliver   (e.g. Fullerton, CA 92014)
```

There are duplicates in the old model so i want to remove those as well.

Comment: Please don't link to content that is integral to you question. In 365 days your question will be useless since the links will have expired. Copy the content of your links into your question.

Comment: Please have a look over at http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/ for well thought-out data models.  Maybe this one: http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/e_commerce/index.htm

Comment: I have updated it to remove links

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your database type. [read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/)

You should be careful to dont loose your data!

Comment: Running postgresql

Comment: One issue was that my original models class (inherited this project), was not  structured properly.  I essentially had to pull out data from specific model fields and transfer them to an brand new, more accurate model class.  It looks cleaner and was able to maintain my old data.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is more to do with the whole relational database schema.

I would have all customer related stuff in one table just like the new CustomerOrder (rename this to Customer) class you have, then create another class for Orders then link the two with a one to many relationship. For example one customer can place many orders. If you want to implement this one to many relationship, simply add the following to the order class:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    # The relavant order fields which you require, i.e. order number etc.
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now when you create a new order instance, you can assign the customer.
p.s. to access in reverse i.e. from customer to order you basically do customer.order_set() method (Customer can place many orders).

Comment: yes i am re-doing the whole schema with the intention of having an Orders Class

Comment: In that case, I suggest you gather the requirements for both Customer and Order classes then have two seperate tables and link them the way I described. Read more on one to many relationship structure from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: Trying to move complete away from the old CustomerOrder class.  Could I do something like this old_name = CustomerOrder.first_name ; new_name = Customer(first_name = old_name)

Comment: Sorry I dont quite get the reason what you're trying to do there. Do you have data that you need to migrate accross? If not just create two new classes.

Comment: actual i see it now.  I want to keep my existing data.  i would just foreign key into the CustomerOrder (original) class.  However, how do you get rid of the duplicates?

Comment: Just a couple of real-world comments.. (i) you probably don't want to delete all orders for a customer when you delete the customer (which is what CASCADE does), since that will delete data from historical accounting/taxes/reporting. (ii) if you're shipping an item you'll want to copy the address to the Order record (you want to know where you shipped something, not what the current customer address is).

Comment: There is no real way of getting rid of the duplicates, you can create a python script and then run it with the django shell command. I suggest you make active use of python manage.py shell command as it will get you a sound understanding of how databases interact in Django.